# Many to one JSON to JSON transformation

Tags: mule, dataweave

I need to transform a set of incoming jsons as below to a common structure at the output. The structure of the incoming jsons are as below

Input JSON 1
{
    "JR_ID": "1",
    "JR_Data": "some text"
}

Input JSON 2
{
    "TA_ID": "1",
    "TA_Data": "some text"
}

Input JSON 3

{
    "IM_ID": "1",
    "IM_Data": "some text"
}

..and many more

The output JSON structure is as below

Output structure

{
    "OBJECT_ID": "1",
    "OBJECT_Data": "some text"
}

The input jsons will come one at a time and the task is to dynamically map the ID field of the incoming JSON to OBJECT_ID of output JSON and same for the data field.

How can I use mule expression language or dataweave for this? Is there any other solution available?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Are you executing this in a for-each scope, and adding to the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that your input seems to map to your output via `*_ID` or `*_Data`, this script should help you out:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
payload pluck ($$ as :string) reduce ((key, out={}) ->
  key match {
    k when key contains "ID"   -> out ++ {"OBJECT_ID":   payload[k]},
    k when key contains "Data" -> out ++ {"OBJECT_Data": payload[k]},
    default                    -> out  
  }
)
```

What this is doing is first getting a list of all the keys in the input object -- `payload pluck ($$ as :string)`. The cast `as :string` is so that we can later test if the key contains a certain substring. Then we use `reduce` to build the output object you're looking for, by adding an `OBJECT_ID` key:value pair to the output object when the input key contains `"ID"` and adding an `OBJECT_Data` key:value pair to the output object when the key contains `"Data"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically map the JSON input using following dataweave syntax:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
{
    OBJECT_ID : payload[0],
    OBJECT_Data : payload[1]
}
```